# Kafka : Switching source from MySQL to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Event data coming from both MySQL and Kafka topics.
We will load historical data from MySQL and then switch to Kafka for current data.Mysql IDs also flows into Kafka . So messages contain event IDs .
Kafka stream events will be processed using a spark job and ultimately ingest data into reporting tables .

Problem : how to load historical data and switch to Kafka source real time .

1-create a temp consumer group to store current offsets from all partitions and current timestamp TS1.

2-Get min ID and Max ID from MySQL table where create date <= TS1. And process through partitions of 500k records .

3-once above processing is done ,pass the timestamp to the main spark job which will process streAming data from the stored offsets , but with event date > TS1
And then continue processing .

There should not be any duplicate records .
What do you think . Any issues with this approach .
I see Timestamp is till seconds . There will be some duplicates as we don’t have precision date till Mili second .

Answer (score 0):

Both Debezium and Kafka Connect JDBC source allow for bulk, snapshot loading into a Kafka topic. No need for Spark.

After initial load, you can keep the DB around for capturing CDC events until you rewrite the producer to send that data actively to its own topic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the timestamp requirements, but changing them, by definition of a Kafka record, will create unique events.

Comment: Sir can you elaborate. Spark jobs are needed for both batch and streaming as We also do some transformations. But that’s not the question. The issue is what and when I will switch the source . In database we have IDs and create date . But Kafka we have offsets for each partition .

Comment: Sure, you currently use a Spark job. I am suggesting the two options listed above as alternatives since this problem can be solved without writing any of your own code. Offsets aren't important. Partitions can just be one, if you must preserve ordering. The topic needs to be created ahead of time, anyway

Comment: I probably did not understand it . Can i Direct message you . That will really help

Comment: Kafka can also have IDs and it definitely has record dates, which are defaulted to "record create date"

Comment: You should edit your post to be more specific about your needs or questions you have

Comment: Yes Kafka messages have the MySQL Id as well . But how do I process exactly where I left off in MySQL ? 
Can u explain in steps . I have mentioned the steps . My problem is my precision is till seconds . In milliseconds thousand messages will pass .

Comment: *"Once the snapshot is complete, Debezium will switch over to using MySQL’s binlog to receive all future database updates"* -- https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/streaming-databases-in-realtime-with-mysql-debezium-kafka

Comment: Thousand events of what? You are querying a database table. Are you saying you are inserting historical records in the middle of the data while a query happens?

Comment: No . Here I ll explain again . Step 1 : capture the current timestamp TS1 and get all offsets of all partitions for a topic .step 2: extract all MySQL events from table where create date < TS1 . To process I ll get min and max id and then parallel process thru partition . Step 3 : start consuming from Kafka topics from all stored offsets with a filter that event date > stored timestamp TS1. 
But this is not a full proof method . Timestamp is till seconds . We might miss some  events during a mill second

Comment: Kafka doesn't care about timestamp precision, only offset ordering. Why do you need to lookup offsets to just insert data from a table? You cannot insert between two offsets in Kafka, so just order the events in the database query. Querying offsets by timestamp is also risky.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have events ordered by time, and therefore might also be processed in order of time by some consumer. If that is the case, you cannot have more than one partition for that action, as spreading events will cause out of order processing

Comment: You can store `seconds * 1000` in Kafka. The filters will still work on ms precision

Comment: So you agree with the steps I mentioned ?i did not get how timestamp * 1000 will solve ? Let’s say I have the current timestamp to ms. But when I take that time stamp and query MySQL table by putting it as create dates upper bound , the MySQL timestamp  column is till seconds . It will miss some events during milliseconds gap . Right ?

Comment: Well, I don't know if Debezium supports filtering timestamps, but I know you can with the JDBC Source Connector. You're welcome to filter the consumer further, but like I said, multiple partitions probably won't work out like you seem to think they will

Comment: Yes we have multiple partition for a topic .

Comment: Okay, and did you read what I wrote about processing timed events from them? In other words, why does timestamp really matter?

Comment: Then what is ur strategy ? Can u elaborate in steps .Will prefer not to use third party tool.

Comment: Spark or JDBC are not already "third party tools"? Kafka Connect is *included with Apache Kafka*, Debezium is a *plugin for Kafka Connect*. Feel free to read over their installation guides, or you can use `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/connect-standalone` on your own, or any single machine